# redirect a page after button click and database update

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I am trying to get a page to redirect after I click the button and after the database updates but it doesnt seem to work.

I have a form that completes in itself, to cut down on the number of pages used (e.g no, thanks content has been edited" page) but after the content has been edited i wish to redirect back home.

form and database update:

```
    <div id = "errormsg">&nbsp;</div>
    <?php 

    echo "<table border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"7\" style=\"font-family:Arial;font-size:11px\">";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><form name=\"confhome\" method=\"post\" action=\"\" onsubmit=\"return valText()\"><textarea name=\"tag\" cols=\"20\" rows=\"3\" id=\"tag\">$row[tagbrief]</textarea></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\"></form></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr></tr>";
        echo "</table><br/>";


    $tagbrief = $_POST['tag'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE quackedup SET tagbrief='$tagbrief' WHERE id='1'");
    ?>
```

JS validation for ref

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valText(){

    var text = document.getElementById('tag');
    var div = document.getElementById('errormsg');

    var lets = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-\'(\)\&\,\:\.\!\?]+$/;

    if((text.value == '') || (text.value == ' ')){
        div.innerHTML="<b>Please enter your changes</b>";
        text.focus();
        return false;}
    else if(text.value.match(lets)){
        div.innerHTML="<b>Content updated</b>";
        return true;}
else {
    return false;}

}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection attacks there - you're using a value from POST without sanitizing it.

Comment: yup thanks :) i plan to sanitize it after i have everything working fully :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully follow but I would rejigger it so it was like this:

```
<?
    if($_POST)
    {
        $tagbrief = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE quackedup SET tagbrief='$tagbrief' WHERE id='1'");

        header("Location: /path/to/script");
        exit;
    }
?>

<div id = "errormsg">&nbsp;</div>
<?php 

echo "<table border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"7\" style=\"font-family:Arial;font-size:11px\">";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><form name=\"confhome\" method=\"post\" action=\"\" onsubmit=\"return valText()\"><textarea name=\"tag\" cols=\"20\" rows=\"3\" id=\"tag\">$row[tagbrief]</textarea></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\"></form></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr></tr>";
    echo "</table><br/>";
?>
```

Now, it only updates the field if you are actually posting the form, and the form contents are escaped for the database (to prevent SQL injection). Just change the /path/to/script to be the path/url you want to go to.

Comment: thats great! works a treat. the only bit i had to change was change header location to a meta refresh becasue the header had already been sent. ill read through it in a hope to learn from it for myself.
thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to write 
`header("Location:/");` 
I hope this will help you